# drink vs drink of

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verb-agreement

I am having trouble with these two sentences:

> - He drinks of the spring.
> - He drink the spring.

Are these two sentences correct? Do they have the same meaning?

By the way, is there anyone having any suggestion for Chinese students in English?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.  Also, I added "verb-agreement" to the tags.  Click that tag to see numerous other questions with answers about subject-verb agreement.

Comment: Both of those sentences are kind of awkward but "He drinks the spring" means he drank the whole spring which wouldn't make sense.  I'm not sure why you're using "drinks" as opposed to drinking or drank but anyway . . . I'd say, "He drinks *from* the spring."  (Or "He is drinking from the spring.", or "he drank from the spring.")

Answer (score 3):

As Kristina Lopez mentioned in the comments, the word you want here is *from*:

> He drinks *from* the spring.

Generally, in English, we say that a person [or animal, etc.] drinks *from* a container or a body of water. However, when we talk about the substance a person is drinking, no preposition is used:

> He drinks orange juice with his breakfast. [Correct] 
>   He drinks of orange juice with his breakfast. [Incorrect]

We can combine these two to refer to both the substance and the container:

> She drank coffee *from* a mug.

*Of* is rarely used in this way in modern English. It sounds old-fashioned and poetic. You will encounter it, for instance, in translations of the Bible:

> ... but whoever drinks *of* the water that I will give him shall never thirst ...
> (John 4:14, NASB)

So, to return to your example sentences,

> He drinks the spring.

would probably be perceived as incorrect by a native English speaker.

> He drinks *of* the spring.

is technically correct, but sounds unusual.

Answer (score 1):

"He drinks of the spring" is a more poetic usage.  One would generally "drink from" a spring, or any other container or source of water.  One can "take a drink of" a liquid, but that's using a gerund (the noun form of the verb drink.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is not incorrect. It would be better (and more normal) if you write *from* instead of *of*.
As for your second sentence, it is incorrect. The verb following a singular subject always ends with an ***s*** or an ***es*** (provided it is written in the present tense).

Comment: Present perfect doesn't require "s" or "es."

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry. I should edit my answer. Thanking you for pointing out.